# Angular RXJS return array of 3 observable streams

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular8

I need to use the following 3 steams to create an array of each. IE: `[homePage, mainNavigation, loan_originators]`

But this only returns `mainNavigation`

```
  const homePage = this.flamelinkService.getData('homePage');
  const mainNavigation = this.flamelinkService.getNav('mainNavigation');
  const loan_originators = this.catalogApiService.get('loan_originators', qry);

  return mainNavigation.pipe(
    concat( homePage, loan_originators),
    first(),
    tap( async navResolveData => {
      // navResolveData = navResolveData[0];
      _log('== Navigation Data Resolver ==> ', 't', navResolveData);
      if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
        this.transferState.set(INFO_KEY, navResolveData);
      }
    }),
  );
```

here im trying forkJoin. but nothing

```
  const homePage = this.flamelinkService.getData('homePage');
  const mainNavigation = this.flamelinkService.getNav('mainNavigation');
  const loan_originators = this.catalogApiService.get('loan_originators', qry);
  return forkJoin([homePage, loan_originators, mainNavigation]).pipe(
    first(),
    tap( async navResolveData => {
      // navResolveData = navResolveData[0];
      _log('== Navigation Data Resolver ==> ', 't', navResolveData);
      if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
        this.transferState.set(INFO_KEY, navResolveData);
      }
    }),
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use forkJoin in this case

```
forkJoin(
  [
   this.flamelinkService.getData('homePage'),
   this.flamelinkService.getNav('mainNavigation'),
   this.catalogApiService.get('loan_originators', qry)
  ]
).subscribe(([res1, res2, res3]) => {
       // do something
});
```